# Ubuntu 18.04 became veryl slow after unsuccessful copying operation

Tags: boot, 18.04

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. I tried to copy some files (about 100GB) from an external USB 3 HD and after reaching about 50% the system hung so I had to forcely shutdown the laptop.

The next time I tried to boot it failed to boot and showed the error:
Failed to start flush journal to presistent storage.

I searched for this problem but couldn't find solutions. After several restarts the system finally could boot. (I don't think I did something special I just restarted the laptop several times. Maybe it needed a lot of time to flush the journal and in each restart it did some work before the 90 second time out until it could finish the job).

Now the system is very slow for some reason. I can't even open a video without the system lagging. I have 8GB of memory and while watching it with system monitor not even 4GB are used. Also the system partition has 100GB free.

Edit: after restarting it again the journal problem happened again. Restarted for second time it was solved. It seems this problem is not completely solved yet.

Thanks.

Comment: suddenly everything worked perfectly. It seems restarting the system is really a magic solution for most of the problems!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just restarted the laptop several times. Let it cool up for a while. And it worked perfectly!